# Is [FromQuery] applied on complex type instead of passing 10+ arguments a good idea for a GET endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, optimization, refactoring, endpoint

For the sake of brevity and easier refactoring, I feel like I shouldn't have method calls spanning 2 lines of code just because their signature contains 10+ arguments. I feel like I should wrap them in an object.

Is that a bad idea to do in a ASP.NET Core HTTP GET action method?

We are talking about an endpoint, accepting simple parameters (of type int, string etc). No collections, arrays, or anything complicated like that.

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: If the the arguments are related and it makes sense to put them into a class: yes. Otherwise no ? Or why does the method take so many arguments, split it into multiple methods.

Comment: I have also passed the parameters in the body also in GET request

Comment: @viveknuna passing a body in a GET request is forbidden. You should even get an error I believe? (Not at compile time, but when making the request)

Comment: @nanu_nana because it's an endpoint? I can't just split an endpoint in two.

Comment: @SpiritBob it is still allowed. PostMan also allows it to send HTTP request with body

Comment: @viveknuna woah, you are correct! I wonder why, specs suggest against doing that sort of thing. Context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/11272124